# Kubernetes kind of objects and Prometheus operator

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus, prometheus-operator

Please help me to understand one thing about `Prometheus` and `Prometheus operator` integration into Kubernetes.

From the documentation I see that a new and not standard kinds of Kubernetes objects are used to configure `Prometheus operator`. By standard kinds I mean `Pod`, `Service`, `ReplicaSet`, `Deployment` etc. How the new like `PrometheusRule` and `Prometheus` was created? There is a point of integration here?

The documentation which brings me to this questions is here https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/alerting.md

The example of this kind of Kubernetes object YAML

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 2
  alerting:
    alertmanagers:
    - namespace: default
      name: alertmanager-example
      port: web
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      team: frontend
  ruleSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: alert-rules
      prometheus: example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Kubernetes [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/).